# Using jQuery, JSON and AJAX to populate a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

like the title says, I am trying to create a drop down menu using jQuery, JSON and AJAX, although I am familiar with the theory I have yet to put it into practice, any advice, demo code snippets or tutorials would be appreciated, since I would like to get off to the best possible start!

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Your question is too broad and has many unknowns. What server technology are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do $.getJSON call to fetch json from server on document.load or on some other event http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ . After that you have to loop through the data and append it to your select box. see that http://www.jsfiddle.net/Dyc9Y/1/

```
<select id="fillME"></select>
<button id="startFilling" value="">Start ajax</button>
$(function(){
 var json = {
                 "0":  {"title":"localjsonOPtion1", "value":"b"},
                 "1":  {"title":"localjsonOPtion2", "value":"a"}
            };

  $("#startFilling").click(function(){

    $.getJSON("http://localdev.myvouchercodes.co.uk/local/default/search/jsonresponse", function(data){
         $("#fillME").html("");
        for(key in data)
            $("#fillME").append("<option value='"+json [key].value+"'>"+json[key].title+"</option>");
        for(key in json)
            $("#fillME").append("<option value='"+json [key].value+"'>"+json[key].title+"</option>");
   });    
 });
});
```

offcourse above example depends on json with following format.

```
{ 
   "0":  {"title":"option1", "value":"1"},
   "1":  {"title":"option2", "value":"2"}
}
```

**EDITED:**
You also need to be familiar with select box change event http://api.jquery.com/change/ and **:selected selector** that will allow you to fetch selected option from the selectbox
http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/    like  `$("select option:selected")`

Comment: also you can view this tutorial http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-jquery-select-box-manipulation-plugin/

Comment: Awesome, thanx for all the info! Ill be going through it in a bit! Will report back with questions or a success story!

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply, but I am going through the code now, and I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607026/jquery-json-drop-down-not-populating

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
$.getJSON("test.php", function(data){
  $.each(data, function(index, text) {
    $('#mySelect').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text)
    );
  });
});
```

note: test.php should return an json encoded array

Comment: Thanx so much, I will try it out in a bit and report back to you guys!