# jQuery JSON drop down not populating

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to create a drop down list using jQuery, PHP and mySQL, here is my code thus far,

HTML:

```
<select id="box"></select><br />
<input id="button" type="button" value="populate" />
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function (){     
        $.getJSON("test_post.php", function(data){

            $.each(data, function(user) {
                $('#box').append(
                    $('<option></option>').html(user)
                );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', '1234');
mysql_select_db('json');
$test = mysql_query('SELECT user,pass FROM login WHERE user="john"');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test, true)) {
    $data .= json_encode($row);
};

echo $data;
```

I have 3 entries in the database, and when I run the 'test_post.php' file, it echoes out the JSON, but when I try and get it to populate the drop down, nothing happens!

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you looked at your server AJAX response with Firebug or the like to make sure you are getting what you expect?

Comment: Yes I have, and it seems to be returning everything as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

**First:** attempt to use undefined variable `$data`, you should have initialized it to an empty string before `while` loop: `$data = '';`, otherwise this can send PHP notice with the JSON response, depending on values of `display_errors` and `error_reporting` settings.

**Second:** as @shamittomar said, `$data` must be an array and `json_encode()` must be called only once for the whole array. For now, you're sending **several** JSON objects concatenated to a single string, which is wrong.

**Third:** value of the `user` function parameter in the JavaScript is actually an **index** of the `data` array, not a **value**, but even if `user` would be a value, it would be a JavaScript **object** with `user` and `pass` properties, not a **string**.

Resulting code should be (changed parts only):

**PHP**

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test, true)) {
    $data[] = $row;
};

echo json_encode($data);
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.each(data, function(i, user) {
    $('#box').append(
        $('<option></option>').html(user.user)
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanx for pointing out my mistakes, I really appreciate that, this way I can learn from them! Also, that code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Try taking `json_encode` out of while loop and encoding it at the end. Like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test, true))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
```

**[EDIT]: After OP comment:**

If you just want the name of the user in the drop down, then do it like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test))
{
    $data[$row['user']] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
```

Comment: The drop down is populating ow, but with 0,1,2 the whole time, I am assuming that it is because it is getting the array index value?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried validating the JSON?
jQuery is quite picky about it's JSON: it needs to validate correctly, no comments and the right content-type!
Try adding the following in your PHP to see if it helps (I always do this)

`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

First of all check mysql connection code is ok?

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', '1234');
```

Updated php code as below,

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', '1234');
mysql_select_db('json');
$test = mysql_query('SELECT user,pass FROM login WHERE user="john"');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test, true)) {
    $data['pass '] = $row['pass'];
    $data['user'] = $row['user'];
 };

echo json_encode($data); die();
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#button").click(function (){  
    $.getJSON('getDropdownData.php', '',function(data){
        $("#box").remove();
        $('<option />', {value: '', text: 'Select option'}).appendTo("#box");
        $.each(data,function(key, value){
             $('<option />', {value: key, text: value}).appendTo("#box");
        });
    });
});
```

Then you will get a dorpdown with pass as "option value" and user as "option text".